# Why my clang-format formated C++ code getting a result as `task && t` rather than `task&& t`?

Tags: c++, clang-format

The relative clang-format config is:

```
Language: Cpp
BasedOnStyle: Google
PointerAlignment: Left
DerivePointerAlignment: false
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
...
```

I have surely configure the `PointerAlignment` as `Left`. When I format my code, I still get a result as

```cpp
    task(task && t) noexcept : coro_handle_(t.coro_handle_) { t.coro_handle_ = nullptr; }
```

rather than

```
    task(task&& t) noexcept : coro_handle_(t.coro_handle_) { t.coro_handle_ = nullptr; }
```

At the same time, the other line of my code is formatted correctly:

```
    task& operator=(const task&) = delete;
    task& operator=(task&& other) noexcept {
        ...
    }
```

What's wrong with the code or clang-format? What's the reason for the problem, and how can that problem be solved / avoided?

Comment: which situations is it not aligning correctly? In constructors only? Or any other cases?

Comment: What version of clang-format?

Comment: It is not aligning correctly in constructors only. My clang-format's version is `clang-format version 11.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git b55009df666a2795741040aff87a5af5a69ec339)`.

Comment: Worthwhile trying out the latest stable LLVM 15 suite as of now, if the formatting is still off, then should file an issue with the LLVM project